# Effects of 75 degrees (Celcius) on human body

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

Question: How long can a person survive before effects of heat stroke start to affect them.

Situation. A person is in a room that is heated up to 75 C (167 F). Let's assume person is naked (so we don't have to factor in clothing or other resistances).

I already know the basics of heat stroke and symptoms, but nothing I find helps me figure out how quickly the human body absorbs heat from the environment (without complex math that is seriously not my forte).

EDIT1:

Let's paint a picture, and see if that helps illustrate the nature of the question.

Person A is a soldier, so we can assume fit, and in the desert. Minimal humidity. Gentle breeze. No water to re-hydrate.

Comment: Temperature is just something at random. Hotter than you find naturally out there, but not so extreme that it's comparable to an oven.

Comment: This is going to be very dependent on the details of the heat, how applied, the person, their health, humidity and how they can hydrate.  There's no single answer for this, IMO.

Comment: @StephenG I could add more factors, but putting in even temperature gives me the itch to say it's being too specific.

Comment: Do the added parameters help?

Comment: Hello Alexandra, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read through the two Help Center pages shown here: [help/on-topic], and [help/dont-ask]. It'll help you understand how the site works. As for your question, let me give you some insight, while living in Finland I regularly enjoyed Sauna at 110℃ for periods up to 45 minutes. Yup, it's honking hot, but it's completely survivable. My point? Touching a stove top at 110℃ would burn you instantly and walking through a desert very long would be horrific. (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... meaning *how* the heat is transferred is incredibly important. It also matters what kind of shape the person is in. Back then, I was young and in great shape. I suspect I'd last about 10 minutes in the same sauna today. Also, I was buck nekid in sauna, but a person swathed in clothing that kept the sweat close to the body would suffer a lot more. Conclusion: there's no single right answer, but the harder it is to evaporate the water from the body, the higher the fat content of the body, and the older the heart of the victim, the shorter the period of time they'd last.

Comment: Heat lamp creates more issues here, because now the human is effectively heated by the heat lamp _and_ surrounding atmosphere. We'll need to know its exact wattage or energy flux and how a person in positioned under it.

Comment: My view would be that you could not reasonably make a statement about the effect on humans in general, because individuals will range from being OK for a short while (?) to passing out and rapidly expiring.  A body temperature of more than 40C will cause heatstroke and it can happen at lower temps.

Comment: Uh. If I give all those specifics, isn't this going to just get flagged as 'story specific' and not get an answer? I mean, I don't mind rattling off the details, but I'm trying to keep it as useful to others who might require related information?

Comment: It might be worth reading https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/04/science/randall-munroe-xkcd-temperature.html as well.  The estimate of an hour or two given by others here seems about right.

Comment: @AlexandraWilliams Adding details does not make your question story specific. On Worldbuilding Stack Exchange, "question reusability" is used a little differently. You can give the most specific scenarios and if every detail given is relevant to the question, it will be fine. What is reusable from question to question is not so much the specific answer, but how one gets there: what sources one uses, which formulae, which insights. The only limitation on details is that at some point this becomes just a physics problem; generally these questions should allow different answering approaches.

Comment: @AlexandraWilliams Worldbuilding.SE has overlap with Physics.SE, as with Biology.SE. The biggest difference is that if you ask here about human temperature survivability you are often going to get longer answers that may include advice for how your soldier might lengthen their survival with skills taught in the army. That is why it is welcome to provide worldbuilding context - tell us about the problem's background, and also your purpose with the scene or story element. Contrasting; on Biology.SE the same question will get you factual no-fluff answers linking to peer-reviewed research papers.

Comment: @AlexandraWilliams `If I give all those specifics, isn't this going to just get flagged as 'story specific'?` It's the other way around. The more details you give us (e.g., the more world rules or circumstantial conditions you enumerate) the ***less*** likely the Q would be closed as too story-based. It's when you leave those circumstantial issues to our imagination that you risk closure (hence the VTC reason "needs details").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An hour to hours.

Saunas are routinely 90C or above, and people can sit in them for a while. 75 is pretty low, and with low humidity you can sweat off the heat.

It'll be unpleasant, especially if you're not used to it, but you'll live till you start getting dehydrated. Then you'll get heat stress, heat stroke, and death.

[If you adjust the temperature to 100-105 then it'll be enough to disable a fit young adult in a few minutes.](https://www.divapor.com/sauna-articles/sauna-world-championships.php)

Comment: +1. At 75 C, and young and healthy subject, dehydration will be the main issue.

Comment: That's kinda the issue I'm having. So, what temperature would you say becomes hazardous to a (fit) person's health where it becomes dangerous within minutes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda nervous and I don't think I'm asking the question right. But I'm also trying to not make this weird or entirely about my story either.

Comment: 110 C ish is where world record people put the temperature at, with decent humidity. The best one last 15 minutes, the worst just a few minutes. 100-105 is probably appropriate for someone who isn't elite.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help with your story.

Comment: a few minutes might be a little exaggarated. It depends on how used to it you are. I am not as fit as a well trained soldier, but go into the sauna after a workout. The Saunas range from 80 - 110C° 
I usually work my way up to 110C° where I stay around 15 minutes. Take a shower. Relax. And go another 15. 3 Times. 
After that I feel quite relaxed. Sure sometimes when the workout was really hard and I didnt drink a lot the last couple of minutes in 110C° make me dizzy. But this is more than a couple of minutes, I am already dehydrated and I am not that fit.

Comment: Just looked it up. World record is at ~19 minutes at 110C°. The difference is, they pour water over the hot stone EVERY 30 seconds. The hot Sauna I go in is quite dry. The Saunas that get water regularly at like 95C° feel way more uncomfortable. So high humidity is what kills you way more than just the heat.

Comment: dry vs. wet: Wet air holds a lot more heat per volume. That means that a person sitting in hot wet air has more heat hitting their skin over time. Also, dry air allows for evaporation which cools the skin.